# How to Update a database row

Tags: java, hibernate

Basically I want to check if the user exists I want to update with the new object `settings`. I got stuck on the update clause. How can I do this??

I want to ***update ALL the data from settings*** not only user string.

```
   Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.setBaselineImg(baselineImg);
    settings.setGitlabUrl(gitlabUrl);
    settings.setGitlabToken(gitlabToken);
    settings.setProfileProject(profileProject);
    settings.setWebCSRProject(webCSRProject);
    settings.setWebAdminProject(webAdminProject);
    settings.setWebClientProject(webClientProject);
    settings.setDockerHostname(dockerHostname);
    settings.setDockerIP(dockerIP);
    settings.setDockerPort(dockerPort);
    settings.setUser(user);

    //if settings for this user already exist just Update them
    CheckIfSettingsForUserExist(user,settings);
    //else Add to database
    ManageDatabase.AddToDatabase(settings);

}

private static void CheckIfSettingsForUserExist(String user, Settings settings) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        String hql = "FROM Settings s WHERE s.user = :user";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("user",user);
        //If settings for user already exist
        if(query.list().size() > 0)
        {
            //Update
            String hqlUpdate = "UPDATE FROM Settings";
            Query queryUpdate = session.createQuery(hqlUpdate);
            queryUpdate.setParameter("user", user);

        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update settings set user =  :user");
query.setParameter("user",user);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

I hope there is going to be a where clause in the query because this update will update all the rows to new user (string value).

Comment: I dont want to update only the user. I want to update with object `settings` that has a lot of parameters (also user)

Comment: but you are passing `String user` in the function, isn't it string?

Comment: Check my code now please. I want to update ALL the data with new one. Something like `Update Settings with new settings where user= :user`

Comment: settings.setUser(user); here user is string?

Comment: then update all the details as update settings set col_1= col_1_new_value, col_2 = col2_new_value ....... where user = :user

Comment: that's boring as hell. isn't there a better way? Can't I pass the object itself? Otherwise hibernate is useless...

Comment: read about `saveOrUpdate`? you are using HSQL, you can play directly with objects.Update the value and call object.save() method.